# How to cut some part of bitmap and overlay it in the fixed position

Tags: android, bitmap

`Bitmap cut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, 100,100);

`[image]

How to put in the fixed position ?

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap.createBitmap()` returns an immutable Bitmap.
To draw something, you need 4 basic components:

- a Bitmap to hold the pixels,
- a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap),
- a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap),
- and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing)

Take a look at [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)